# Write concern requires callback - Mongoose + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a following problem. I'm creating project management app and when I remove a milestone, I want to unset its ID from ReportEntry document and add milestone's title to another attribute of ReportEntry. I've got following code:

```
MilestoneSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('ReportEntry').update(
        {milestone: this._id},
        {$unset: {milestone: ""}},
        {$set: {removedMilestone: this.title}},
        {multi: true},
        next
    );
});
```

This doesn't work, it throws in node.js console an error: writeConcern requires callback at updateWithWriteCommands (path). What's wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose's [Model#update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method accepts only 4 parameters with callback being the last. You're passing 5.

Try this:

```
this.model('ReportEntry').update(
    {milestone: this._id},
    {
        $unset: {milestone: ""},
        $set: {removedMilestone: this.title},
    },
    {multi: true},
    next
);
```

Comment: @user3216673 You're welcome. Could you mark this as the correct answer then?